# Using XR2206 function generator with split supply

Tags: function-generator

I have an [Exar XR2206](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/146/exar_xr2206-195595.pdf) to generate triangle wave with single supply Vcc. This wave has peak value 12 volt and 0 volt.

How to make this IC operate in split-supply?

Hence I got triangle wave with peak value +6 Volt and -6 Volt.

Comment: Are they still selling those?  (I thought they went obsolete.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold They've been obsolete for a solid 5 years now.

Comment: I still find it on local market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XR2206 will operate just fine from split supplies. All you have to do is tie all ground pins to V-. See pages 10 and 11 of the datasheet.

Comment: Oh, I got it. How about pin 12 (ground pin) of this IC? Should I connect it to negative voltage supply?

Comment: Tie all ground pins to V-.

Comment: I have dual supply with three pins, +V, 0 V, and -V. If all ground pins are tied to V-, how about pin 0 V of the supply? Just left it opened?

Comment: Per the datasheet, the resistor tied to the MO pin can be tied to 0V.

Comment: Does it mean i need to tie 0V to the node between resistor 5.1 kOhm?

Comment: Yes, then you can get rid of the 5.1k resistors all together.

Comment: And also rid +V connected to the 5.1k resistor right?

Comment: Yes, all it will do at that point is waste power.

Comment: Hihi. I'm sorry for asking too much n detail. This is my 2nd hardware project. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a level shifting op-amp circuit to subtract 6V from the signal or, if the lowest frequency you need is hundreds of Hz a simple high pass RC filter with a cut-off around a few Hz would remove the DC level and centralize it without altering the shape too much.

Alternatively, if you didn't mind losing half the amplitude you could use this circuit: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGnB6Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I need a 10 kHz triangle wave. I think level shifting op-amp is a good option.

Comment: @Sidqi to be honest I think Matt's answer is probably the way forward unless you don't (or can't) have a -6V supply.

Comment: Yes, i agree. Thank you very much for your suggestion, Sir.